# Will I be stuck on the Chrome developer version forever?

Tags: google-chrome

I am using the Google Chrome **developer** version (v.19 right now) since several months.

But due to all the crashes and whatnot, I want to go back. Which doesn't work!

My Google (Chrome) profile data is the cloud, but when I uninstall Chrome and reinstall the stable or beta version, it always says something along the lines of **"profile data is incompatible"** !

But why does Google save such profile data in such a non-sensible way in the first place?? I mean we're only talking about extension data and user profile settings - and: Open tabs from "Session buddy"!

And **does that mean, that I'm with the dev version stuck forever** until Google decides to resolve this? I mean how am I supposed to downgrade now that all my profile data seems to be "contaminated" with data fragments that show that I ran a developer version of Google Chrome?

I am sure not the first one with this problem (a quick search on here didn't show me any results though).

**UPDATE:**

### I was just auto-upgraded (forcefully!) from Google on Chrome v.20 dev!

That is really not what I expected. So it seems all what was said here is wrong!

I need a solution to stop Chrome from auto-updating me.

Comment: I actually face the same problem. Maybe you can just sync everything with Google and then start a new Chrome profile?

Comment: I went back to the stable build too because one of my developer tools won't work with the latest developer build.

However, for me it's not a big deal:

* I think Google is in the middle of transitioning the profiles to the cloud so syncing will be easier (hopefully within this year).  
* I have two machines and don't really depend on everything being synced - I have my bookmarks on pinboard.in and manage my extensions by hand because I have some that aren't on the web store.  
* I will go back to the dev build as soon as my project is finished (just to get rid of that pop-up)

Comment: Can somebody by the way explain me why this was moved to SU? Because Chrome is a software?

Comment: That'd be why, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And does that mean, that I'm with the dev version stuck forever until Google decides to resolve this? I mean how am I supposed to downgrade now that all my profile data seems to be "contaminated" with data fragments that show that I ran a developer version of Google Chrome?

You won't be able to use the profile data with a stable build till the stable build reaches the same version as the dev build. The stable builds are about 6 weeks behind the developer build.

Comment: Thanks! So it seems I really have to wait six weeks? A bit disappointing in my opinion. I'm just lucky that right now Chrome works quite fine, but this is not a solution for people who have urgent, repeatable problems with a flawed Google Chrome dev build!

Answer (score 0):

- Sync the data you want to keep to a Google Account
- Uninstall Chrome
- Delete whatever is left of %LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome
- Install stable version
- Sync to Google Account to get yout profile back

(You may lose some settings and extension data this way. You could probably keep your %LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions. As always make a backup of %LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome in case something goes wrong.)

Answer (score 0):

A simple Google search brought this up:
http://dev.chromium.org/administrators/turning-off-auto-updates

As well as (the only option that I could access, thus worked for me): "Go to Start > Run (type run in search box) > msconfig, switch to Services tab, then uncheck Google Update Service and hit OK."
**Source:** http://www.techzilo.com/disable-prevent-google-chrome-auto-update/

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me once when I tried the 64bit edition before it's official release, I had to delete my profile files, after uninstalling but then I just let them resync from my account so I didn't have to reload all my extensions etc.

- Also if something ever does get stuck in your sync profile it can be cleared from googles webpage. Just get a spare browser to export your bookmarks/history first to save it then import it back afterwords if you ever get stuck that badly though.

  P.S. I find some uninstallers like Revo actually work well to help find and remove everything an uninstall doesn't automatically, (at least most the time).