# Can't open Paypal.com with Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, paypal

Currently I always get an error message (since one week!) trying to open the PayPal website with Google Chrome and I don't know why. FlashBlocker and AdBlockPlus are deactivated. v.20.0.1132.11 dev.

**Error message:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
**<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
Size of a request header field exceeds server limit.<br />**
<pre>
Cookie: Apache=10.190.8.170.1302997118916547; (cookie body removed due to privacy reasons)
</pre>
</p>
</body></html>
```

Comment: This happens only in Chrome? Have you tried the stable version of Chrome (v19) instead of the dev one?

Comment: I can't change to the stable version. See problem described here: http://superuser.com/questions/403966/will-i-be-stuck-on-the-chrome-developer-version-forever Or at least I didn't make the effort to follow the solution described, because I know no one who tested it and can confirm that it works without any data loss.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With dev Chrome version, simply access the paypal web from the incognito Chrome window. No need for clearing cache and cookies as the problem will show up after some time anyway and you want your cookies and cache for other stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Clear your cache and cookies.  That fixed it for me, temporarily.  It still happens regularly and I have to go clear the data each time.  I wish I could provide a more permanent fix.

Comment: Confirming, this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems they have a problem rerouting per country the users who typed in www.paypal.com - the link is different if you click the 1st result from google.com You'll get `https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/home` or depending on what country are you, the `us` (United States) part will change.

The solution is to search Paypal in Goggle. Be sure to bookmark it the next time. Its not our browser who has a problem, its how they route the user to their specific country (link).

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

What helped me:

1. Deactivate Windows Firewall
2. Log in into paypal on Chrome
3. Active Windows Firewall again
4. Profit